# Dropdrown button dentro de <ul>

Tags: html5

Este es el `dropdown-button` "Multimedia" y su CSS:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 15.8%;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
 right:1129px;
 top:47px;
 border:1px solid #939496;
 left:0px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 font-size:30px;
 
}


button:hover{
 background-color: #4dd6e2;
    color: white;
}


li a.active {
    background-color: #309ba5;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #4dd6e2;
    color: white;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
 width:22px;
 height:50px;
 font-family:Times New Roman;
 text-align:middle;
 
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
 top:-88px;
 right:572px;
 
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #4dd6e2;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Multimedia</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="mp4.html">MP4</a>
    <a href="png.html">PNG</a>
    <a href="gif.html">GIF</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este el es menú:

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="aboutme.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Multimedia</a></li> <!--Aqui va el dropdown-->
</ul>
```

Quiero meter el `dropdown-button` en el `<li>`, pero si lo meto, no funciona. Alguien sabe cómo solucionar esto?

Comment: el problema está en el CSS ya que estás poniendo unos valores en `.dropdown` que sacan el botón de su sitio y no se ve. Prueba a modificar o eliminar el `top` y el `right` de ese `div`

Comment: <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="aboutme.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
  <li>
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Multimedia</button>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
 <a href="mp4.html">MP4</a>
 <a href="png.html">PNG</a>
 <a href="gif.html">GIF</a>
 </div>
 </div>
  </li>
</ul>
Tengo esto, pero no funciona.

Comment: He quitado el top y el right del div

Comment: mira esto: https://jsfiddle.net/2j0vcpsk/1/ he cambiado algun ancho para que se vea mejor pero el problema es que no se veía el dropdown

Comment: Realmente tu dropdown-button por sí solo tampoco se muestra.

Comment: @JuanVan12 en lugar de añadir contenido en los comentarios, dale a [editar] para incorporarlos en la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

El único problema que veo es que le estás dando una posición al menú que hace que se salga de la pantalla y no se vea, porque por lo demás, parece funcionar correctamente. Los estilos a los que me refiero son estos:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    top:-88px;   /* <---------------- este valor   */
    right:572px; /* <---------------- y este valor */
}
```

De hecho, esos valores son increíblemente específicos, no me extrañaría que los tuvieses ahí por algún motivo (aunque no parecen una solución ideal), pero no tienen sentido dentro del ejemplo que pones en la pregunta.

Así, si pones tu mismo código quitando ese posicionamiento de los estilos, verás como el dropdown ya está visible y funciona (aunque parece que le falta algo de estilo a las opciones):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15.8%;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
  right:1129px;
  top:47px;
  border:1px solid #939496;
  left:0px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:30px;

}


button:hover{
  background-color: #4dd6e2;
  color: white;
}


li a.active {
  background-color: #309ba5;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #4dd6e2;
  color: white;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:22px;
  height:50px;
  font-family:Times New Roman;
  text-align:middle;

}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /*top:-88px;
  right:572px;*/
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #4dd6e2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="aboutme.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Multimedia</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="mp4.html">MP4</a>
        <a href="png.html">PNG</a>
        <a href="gif.html">GIF</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Para que el ancho se vea mejor, podrías quitarle el `width:22px` al dropbtn y hacer que la lista tenga un `overflow-x:hidden` para que no aparezcan las barras de scroll.

Comment: Eso es, ademas el botón `.dropbtn` tiene un ancho de 22 píxeles que hace que no se despliege correctamente el menú, eliminando ese valor mejora bastante